# git ssh problems

Tags: ssh, git

I have a git repo I am trying to use this command on a remote.

```
$ git push origin master
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

I am trying to do this with GitBash.

I generally login with ssh ONLY through Putty, so I know my key works and is there.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What does `.git/config` say about your remote origin?

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but the "host" is a blank space.

Comment: Missing info would be the contents of `git remote show origin`; we don't now where you're trying to push.

Comment: Which OS are you running the client on? Which OS is the server running on?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399106/pushing-to-github-from-work-bad-file-number-error has an accepted answer that suggests that the problem can be caused by trying to push through a proxy.  How exactly that works with SSH I'm not sure, but since the answer is accepted I'd expect that the problem there was a proxy, and fixing it or removing it from the equation solved the problem.

Comment: No proxy, This is totally with a local network.

Comment: I can log into the machine with my Putty and id_sha keys. But I get this:Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly when I try to use git bash.

Comment: Why are you adding information pertinent to your question in a comment to my answer?  Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

> No proxy, This is totally with a local network.

Please post the output of `git config -l`, or at least `git config --get http.proxy`?

> I can log into the machine with my Putty and id_sha keys. But I get
>   this: `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly` when I try to use git bash.

Did you take a look at the sshd logs?

Anyway, use HTTP to push to see what happens:

```
# git remote rm origin
# git remote add origin https://git.domain.com/project/repo.git
# git config --global http.sslVerify false
# git push origin master
```